# Output .aar file to different app project libs directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
            //def fileName = "apc-${defaultConfig.versionCode}.aar"
            def fileName ="apc.aar"
           // output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
           output.outputFile = new File('../../App/app/libs/',fileName)
        }
    }
}
```

This error comes
Cannot expand ZIP '/home/raminder/Code/App/app/libs/apc.aar' as it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

It will likely be much cleaner and less error prone to do this as a separate Gradle [`Copy` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html). You can also add a dependency such that this task gets run after every build so you don't need to run the task manually.

Comment: I am already aware of that alternative way.Thanks for it. By the way do u have any suggestion regarding the above error .

Comment: Without more context around the code snippet you have it's hard to tell - if I had to guess, the snippet above is running during configuration so the file doesn't exist yet since the file gets built as part of the Gradle build (after the configuration).

Comment: yes you are right. libraryVariants.all closure is run after the build process.